# Finding the Sum of Rows and Columns in a Two-Dimensional Array (C) using file pointers

Tags: c

There is no row/column information since there are SIZE × SIZE numbers in the input file.
e.g. this what we have in the input file:

```
1 5 8
6 10 2
9 2 16
```

The code reads the data from the input file. After populating the array, I need to calculate and report the row wise and column wise sums of the matrix. For the
example input file above, the output should be look like:

```
row sums: 14 18 27
column sums: 16 17 26
```

I am new to C programming. Can someone guide me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 3
int main(void)
{
    int matrix[SIZE][SIZE];
    int sum=0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("input.txt","r");
    if(fp=NULL)
    {
        printf("File could not read the file!");
        exit(0);
    }
    for(int r = 0; r < SIZE; ++r)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < SIZE; ++c)
        {
            sum += matrix[r][c];
        }
        printf("Row sums: %d \n",sum); // printf("Sum for row %d = %d\n", r, sum);
        sum=0;
        printf("\n");
    }

    for(int r = 0; r < SIZE; ++r)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < SIZE; ++c)
        {
            sum += matrix[c][r];
        }
        printf("Column sums: %d \n",sum);   //printf("Sum for column %d = %d\n", c, sum);
        sum=0;
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `exit(1);` or `exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` to exit a program after an error — not `exit(0)` which indicates "everything worked" (but it didn't).  The error message should also go to `stderr`, not `stdout`, and should include at least the file name (so you shouldn't use a literal string as the argument to `fopen()` because you need to reference it again in the error message).  However, that doesn't affect your main problem.

Comment: Error: `if(fp=NULL)` should be `if(fp==NULL)`. And you didn't read any file data. In the first nested pair of loops you need something like `fscanf(fp, "%d", &matrix[r][c]);`

Comment: Your first pair of nested `for` loops are processing `matrix` before it has been initialized.  Neither you nor I can predict what you'll see, but we can reliably assume it isn't what you want.  In fact, there's no code shown that reads from the file you carefully opened.

Comment: when i run the code, it shows nothing.

Comment: Style-wise, I'd suggest initializing `sum = 0;` before the loop where you increment rather than afterwards.  It is less prone to confusion in the long run, though it is safe enough here.  You could also move the declaration inside the loops: `int sum = 0;` before the inner loops.  Reducing variable scope also helps reduce bugs.

Comment: When ***I*** run your code, it outputs row and column sums with strange values, not nothing.

Comment: Before your first loop, you need to add another pair of nested loops to read the data from the file you opened (after you've fixed the 'assignment vs comparison' problem).  Don't forget to check that `scanf()` returns `1` each time, indicating success (report an error on failure).  Until you do that successfully, you won't get meaningful answers.

Comment: It show the sums seperately. For example, it is like Row sum 14, Row sum 18 Row sum 27... How can i print them together like Row sums 14 18 27 etc

Comment: Use `printf("%s:", "Row sums");` before the loop; use `printf(" %d", sum);` in the loop; and use `putchar('\n');` (or `puts("");` or `printf("\n");`) after the loop.

Comment: I did what you say but i guess i coulnd't do it properly. It shows the same output. I mean seperately.

Comment: Look up examples of `fscanf` to read from the file; don't forget to check the return value.

Comment: you should also close the file when done reading it (which is not done in the code provided)